# Prestashop installation in test directory giving internal server error 500

Tags: php, installation, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

today after finishing my localhost prestashop work, trying to install prestashop on my server to make my site online.
Follow the step right after below

1. uploaded prestashop_1.6.1.6.zip in test directory.
2. trying to run installation in /test directory from firefox.

But gave following

`Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@mysite.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request. `

please Help. i really appreciate it.

Comment: Hello matteo enna,  please give other options if you can..

Comment: check the actual webserver logs

Comment: In config/define.inc.php you have: `define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', false);` change it to `define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);` it supposed to show what is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove www.yourdomain.com/prestashop_path/cache/**class_index.php**
it works for me!